# How do I convert i32 and f32 to [u8; 4]?

Tags: rust, type-conversion

For a programming language VM I have been working on lately I need to create a stack for data. I have decided to use a `Vec<u8>` and then convert data to slices of `u8`.

Although turning strings into `u8` is trivially easy, turning `f32`s and `i32`s into `u8` slices is less obvious. If this were C I would just do a cast; however, that doesn't seem to work in Rust.

What is the best way to convert these types into slices of `u8`?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#method.to_bits; https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.to_le_bytes